# Gitlab API on Docker container not working - curl: (28) Failed to connect

Tags: docker, curl, docker-container, docker-network, gitlab-api

I am trying to use curl to get data using Gitlab API with the ip address of a docker container(Docker on Windows).

It works only when I type the command on the container's CLI on the Docker software, however, when I type the same command `curl "172.17.0.2/api/v4/projects"` on the windows terminal it shows `curl: (28) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 80: Timed out` or `curl : Unable to connect to the remote server` .

Here's a part of the result of `docker inspect`:

```
 "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "c544be6d26c45eb84e2f201f38f72c811d5a5b90e97015720fb72aa42bc9a4e4",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "22/tcp": null,
                "443/tcp": null,
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/c544be6d26c4",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "562cb59fa80dc6098975fa3f24e7b93096f2dde933a1ae28f0bf8c226744d71e",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "cbcc7ef541a440dcb3854e4f4052088f02bf3309cfc483355cc08306c0df2d43",
                    "EndpointID": "562cb59fa80dc6098975fa3f24e7b93096f2dde933a1ae28f0bf8c226744d71e",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                },
                "gitlab-network": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {},
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "55ce0d992658"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "bf29a4d80ac491c97d3fc443dc19962fad0c19b738c635f88315827e6d4d689f",
                    "EndpointID": "12a9cff63959de86bd7adf47cdfca1674fe6a7d4731fdd36d84e0e51c4abfd2d",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": {}
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: That is internal IP address and should not be used as such. Have you tried `curl -X GET http://localhost/api/v4/projects`, since this container's port 80 is mapped to host's port 80.

Comment: Yes that is correct, it works now with localhost as you said, I have tried it before but didn't work, probably was not on port 80, thank you.